# CodeIgniter systemfolder under publicHtml

Tags: codeigniter

I want to move my system and application folder of Codeigniter under the public_html folder.

```
public_html
[folder_name] => application & systemfolder
```

so i change the path's in the index.php and nothing is working.
the site just outputs that the path to the system folder is not correct.

my path is something like

```
/var/www/....
```

and it's correct. 100 %

i think the problem is here:

i have to create the [folder_name] as root, because the ftp_user has not the permission to create a folder.
so i guess it's a permission problem, but i have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I do this where ever possible but you need to update the index.php file that should exist within the `public_html` folder to the new location.

i.e.

```
$application_folder = '../folder_name/application';
$system_folder = '../folder_name/system';
```

That way, only the `index.php` exists in `public_html` but the application/system folders are within your root folder.